# How do I make a Word file out of a .tex file?

Tags: conversion, msword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting TeX to MS-Word for recruiters asking for resumes in word files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38837/converting-tex-to-ms-word-for-recruiters-asking-for-resumes-in-word-files)

Since some resume websites only accept `.doc` (word files).

Now, I'm not a pro user, just have that in mind when you read this next part:

My current resume is a `.tex` file that is compiled using pdflatex, it also uses a `resume.cls`

I just want to get a `.doc` file that is as close to the pdf as possible.

Comment: I know that there is such feature in adobe acrobat reader. But you have to register & pay for it. Furthermore I don't know anything about the results.

Comment: Sounds like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38837/converting-tex-to-ms-word-for-recruiters-asking-for-resumes-in-word-files to me: could you take a look and let us know if this helps?

Comment: I know there is a possibility to create a `HTML` file out of `.tex` files. Maybe its easier to convert `HTML` to `.doc`

Comment: You _can_ get a .doc that is looks like the PDF: Just capture each page as an image and paste that image into the `.doc` file. That is what I would do if someone required a `.doc` file. :-)

Comment: @ Dave: I'll check it out and report back. @ Joseph Wright: I'll check it out and report back. @ Timebandit: I'll try that and report back. @ Peter Grill: Many of these websites need your resume to be text, as they need to parse your resume for keywords.